# How to create Kubernetes TLS secrets with intermediate and root cert

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a TLS secret for our key-cert pair that is issued by Entrust (third party CA) .
The cert has an intermediate CA and a root CA . This [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) has instructions on how to create a TLS secret - but I do not see instructions on how this can be done when we have a root/intermediate CA .

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cert-manager`. they can help you to create secret of `crt` and `key` with your `root ca`. you can check there documentation.

[install cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/)

[details](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/ca/)

Answer (score 0):

I found it here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/auth/client-certs/README.md

```
# kubectl create secret generic ca-secret --from-file=tls.crt=server.crt --from-file=tls.key=server.key --from-file=ca.crt=ca.crt
secret/ca-secret created
# kubectl get secret ca-secret -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FUR...........
  tls.crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FU...........
  tls.key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFU...........
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-24T12:18:05Z"
  name: ca-secret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "60143256"
  uid: 798db0e4-5f95-49cf-8efc-105afa7c719e
type: Opaque
#
```